# Writing data to an array and then to a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that goes through multiple different screens, and has the user enter data, is it possible to chain information between these pages? for instance if I get first name, last name, phone number in the first screen. State, city, zip in the second page, etc etc for a few pages can I pass data from the first screen all the way to the last screen where I would then post them to a database?

NOTE: the whole reason we want to do it this way is to limit the amount of database writes that we do during this process.

Comment: Why not make it a form wizard. http://thecodemine.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a  form and make a design like this with the jquery not by creating different page  and submit the whole data at a single time than you can get the data by either GET or POST

or if you want to do this by among different page you can use the [html5  webstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and on the success submit remove the storage